# Algoritmo de distribuição eletrônica

Tags: php, algoritmo

Estou tentando pensar em um jeito diferente de fazer distribuição eletrônica. O modo como eu fiz foi o seguinte: exibir a quantidade de elétrons em cada camada. Contudo, na distribuição que eu quero (1s² 2s² 2p<sup>6</sup>...) a ordem das camadas não são respeitadas.

A distribuição que eu quero é feita de acordo com o [diagrama de Linus Pauling](http://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_Linus_Pauling), que tem essa ordem aqui: `1s2, 2s2, 2p6, 3s2, 3p6, 4s2, 3d10, 4p6, 5s2, 4d10, 5p6, 6s2, 4f14, 5d10, 6p6, 7s2, 5f14, 6d10, 7p6.` Sendo o número depois da letra a quantidade de elétrons de cada subnível(representados pelas letras) e o número antes da letra a camada/nível.

Eu tinha feito também um desse jeito que eu propus, contudo, ficou muito mal escrito.

Coloquei esses valores do diagrama como string em um array e depois usei e abusei de
`str_replace()`. Ou seja, não fiz um "algoritmo em si".

Para quem não entende de distribuição eletrônica e queira ajudar, vou distribuir um átomo de:

> Número atômico 10 `->` 1s² 2s² 2p<sup>6</sup>
>   Número atômico 11 `->` 1s² 2s² 2p<sup>6</sup> 3s¹
>   Número atômico 14 `->` 1s² 2s² 2p<sup>6</sup> 3s² 3p²

Ou seja, basta seguir aquela ordem do diagrama dali de cima, não precisando preencher todas as vagas para os elétrons, mas nunca ultrapassando o limite.
Então se alguém puder me ajudar, a encontrar um jeito de fazer a distribuição do jeito que eu mencionei, agradeceria.

O meu código ficou o seguinte (Agora, fiz a parte que verifica se a distribuição acaba com 4 ou 9 elétrons no subnível "D", e se assim acontecer, retira um elétron do subnível "S" mais próximo e manda pro "D"):

```
<?php

if ($_GET['atomic_n']) {

$arr_1 = array("1s2", "2s2", "2p6", "3s2", "3p6", "4s2", "3d10", "4p6", "5s2", "4d10", "5p6", "6s2", "4f14", "5d10", "6p6", "7s2", "5f14", "6d10");
$arr_2 = substr_replace ($arr_1, "", 0, 2);
$arr_3 = substr_replace ($arr_1, "", 2);


 $eletrons = $_GET['atomic_n'];
 $contador = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i<=17; $i++) {

        if ($contador < $eletrons) {

            $contador += $arr_2[$i];

            if ($contador < $eletrons) {

                $arr_4[] = "$arr_3[$i]<sup>".$arr_2[$i]."</sup>";

             } else {

               $arr_4[] = $arr_3[$i]."<sup>".($arr_2[$i]-$contador+$eletrons)."</sup>";

             }
   }
}

  $k = 0;
  while ($arr_4[$k]) {
  $ultimo_termo = $k;
  $k++;
  }

$arr_excl = substr_replace ($arr_4, "", 0, 1);

$eletrons_final_2 = substr_replace ($arr_4, "", 0, 2);
$eletrons_final = str_replace ("<sup>", "", $eletrons_final_2);

$subnivel_2 = preg_replace ("/[^a-z]/", "", $arr_4);
$subnivel = str_replace ("sup", "", $subnivel_2);
$nivel = substr_replace ($arr_4, "", 1);

if ( end($arr_excl) == "d<sup>4</sup>" || end($arr_excl) == "d<sup>9</sup>" ) {

 $r = $ultimo_termo;

        while ($r > 0) {


                if ($subnivel[$r] == "s") {

                    $eletrons_final[$r] -= 1;
                    $eletrons_final[$ultimo_termo] +=1;
                    break;

                }

        $r--;

        }

for ($w = 0; $w <= $ultimo_termo; $w++) {

    echo $nivel[$w].$subnivel[$w]."<sup>".$eletrons_final[$w]."</sup>"."<br>";

}



    } else {

      foreach ($arr_4 as $k => $v){
              echo "$v<br>";

      }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: E qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Como eu posso fazer uai..  "A distribuição que eu quero é feita de acordo com o diagrama de Linus Pauling, que tem essa ordem aqui:"

Comment: E o que você já fez?

Comment: Adicionado, mas já adianto que não vai ajudar não. Ele foi feito todo baseado em string...

Comment: Olha... Eu detesto química, mas as duas únicas coisas que eu vejo que você pode fazer a mais é reescrever o algorítimo, usando as ferramentas certas, pras situações certas e, talvez, ordenar os arrays. Talvez porque eu não entendo bulhufas disso, mas com base [nessa tabela](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_eletr%C3%B4nica_dos_elementos_qu%C3%ADmicos_(p%C3%A1gina_de_dados)), o Cobalto (27), por exemplo, até distribuiu certo, mas ficou numa ordem diferente.

Comment: Amigo, é porque aí está separado por camada. Ou seja, todos que começam com o 1, com 2, com 3, etc... Isso é mero detalhe. É só eu pegar no último foreach e mudar. Exibir usando como parâmetro o nível. O maior problema que você não deve saber é o seguinte: Distribuições que acabam com 4 ou 9 no subnível "D" ficam instáveis, então eles retiram um elétron do último subnível S encontrado e passam pro "D". No mais, existem ainda átomos que possuem distribuições totalmente fora da regra, veja o Nióbio... rsrs

Comment: Agora implementei essa regra do último subnível, quem quiser dar uma olhada, e se puder comentar algum erro, algo do tipo, agradeço.